# Drupal elements missing from menu editor

Tags: php, drupal

I have a Drupal 7.57 installation. A user complains that some elements missing when editing articles (it has just a few basic edit buttons, not like on the picture, what I would need).

Anybody can tell me how to enable these?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have CKEditor installed, so go to 
/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full 
click 'Editor appearance' and see "available buttons" in the 2nd box.
Drag the button you need to upper box called "current toolbox".
If function you need is not there/button missing, when you need to install CKEditor plugins to add functionality.

Please note that your user shall have access to 'full HTML' profile.
'Filtered html' profile exclude images by default, that's why user may not see insert 'image' icon/button.